Exponential distribution and random sampling
Statement
It's night and you are looking into the sky waiting to see a falling star. After the first hour you still haven't seen anything, so you check online and find two sources $s_1$ and $s_2$. According to $s_1$ the waiting time is distributed as $p_1(t) = 2e^{-2t}$, according to $s_2$ it's $p_2(t) = 0.3e^{-0.3t}$.
Assuming (only) one of the two is correct and that at first you don't trust one more than the other ( $P(s_1 \text{ is correct}) = P(s_2 \text{ is correct}) = 0.5$ ): What is the probability of seeing the first falling star in the next 1 hour?
Two approaches and problem with them
I used two random variables $C\sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ and $S$ such that $p(S=t|C=0)$ is an exponential of parameter 2 and $p(S=t|C=1)$ is an exponential of parameter 0.3.
The problem is: discordant solution between two different approaches!.

First approach: I use memorylessness of exponential distribution: $$P(1<S<2|S>1) = P(0<S<1)$$ and after computing the calculation $P(S<1|C=0)P(C=0) + P(S<1|C=1)P(C=1)$ I get 56% as a result.
I calculate the probability by sampling:

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import bernoulli, expon

# Number of samples
n_samples = 3_000_000

# Generate Bernoulli samples to choose the distribution
c = bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=n_samples)

# Generate exponential samples based on the outcome of the Bernoulli samples
# Scale for s1 is 1/2 and for s2 is 1/0.3
scales = np.where(c == 0, 1/2, 1/0.3)
s = expon.rvs(scale=scales)

# Filter for the samples where the star is seen in the second hour but not in the first
condition_second_hour = (s > 1) & (s <= 2)
condition_after_first_hour = (s > 1)

# Calculate the probability
probability = np.sum(condition_second_hour) / np.sum(condition_after_first_hour)
print(f'The probability of seeing the first falling star in the second hour given no star in the first hour is approximately {probability:.4f}')

and I get 35%.
Conclusion
I don't understand the wide difference in the results, given that both approaches look right to me!

Your second answer is closer: $35.270786%$ would be even closer if you did the Bayesian calculations.  Your first answer is the probability of seeing a falling star in an hour but ignores the point that you have observed an hour with no falling star and are then interested in the following hour.
